# Azure github deployment fails becuase it can not find some temporary files

Tags: azure, github, deployment

I have a solution with three projects. The structure is Like this:

```
>myApp //solution
    >myApp.domain //class library
    >myApp.data   //class library
    >myApp.web    //web app 
>.gitignore
>.deployment
```

In local environment project works fine. Even if I deploy from Visualstudio it works perfectly fine, however when I deploy it using github, deployment fails. here is the log message:

> Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>   All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>   All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>     myApp.Domain -> D:\home\site\repository\myApp.Domain\bin\Release\myApp.Domain.dll
>   CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs' could not be found [D:\home\site\repository\myApp.Data\myApp.Data.csproj]
>   CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs' could not be found [D:\home\site\repository\myApp.Data\myApp.Data.csproj]
>   CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs' could not be found [D:\home\site\repository\myApp.Data\myApp.Data.csproj]
>   Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\myApp.Web\myApp.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\6bb414c0-d47f-480d-8db4-9a08459a55b5";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository.\"
>   An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\45.40609.1605\bin\scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd

It seems deploy process **couldn't find some files** inside `obj`directory.
I downloaded my `.gitignore` from [github gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore), also according to this [microsoft documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) there is no need for including build files.

I changed `.gitignore`to include that specific folder (`obj/Debug`), but it also failed.

Finally, I copied my entire project somewhere else. Then I deleted both `.gitignore`and `.git`. I created another github repository and I pushed **everything**. This time Azure deploys it **successfully**.

Also here is `.deployment` file:

```
[config]
project = myApp.Web/myApp.Web.csproj
```

**My question is**
Do I need to include build output files to my repository?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: anything in the bin/ or the obj/ directories (or anything else generated at the compile stage for that matter) of any of your projects should not be required to deploy to Azure.

For my azure projects I have set my git ignore file to completely ignore both the the bin folder and the obj folder - also the suo files amongst many others. However simply having these folders listed in your gitignore file **will not** automatically remove any files from these folders that you have already committed.

Personally I would completely delete the bin and obj folder from your disk and then ensure that if git status lists any files from those directories as removed - that you commit those deletions to your repository. Then because those folders are in your .gitignore file - any future files created in bin or obj directories will not be included in your repository.

A good example of a .gitignore file customized specifically for Visual Studio is the one you've already found at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore - a git ignore file from (or at least in a repository maintained by) the developers of github.